I use react, and react hokes router, and router dont update page
my component
 

import React from "react";
//import HeadingRow from './HeadingRow';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Results from './Results';
 import {useRoutes,
  useParams, Outlet, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
          
import Card from './Card';



class Services extends React.Component {
         

          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            console.log(props);
            this. state = {
            cards: [],
            cardsError: "",
            id: props.id
          };
            
          }
        fetchServices = async (id) => {
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/cards/${id}`);
            const data = await res.json();

            return data;
          };
        fetchgetServiceseses = async () => {
            const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/cards`);
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);
            return data;
          };
 

        async componentDidMount() {

            const {id} = this.state;
                
                if(id){

                    const data_card = await this.fetchServices(id);
                    const cards = [data_card] ;
                    this.setState({cards });
                    console.log(id);
                    console.log(cards);

                }else{

                        const cards = await this.fetchgetServiceseses();
                  this.setState({ cards });
                }

        }
        async componentDidUpdate() {

                const {id} = this.state;
                    
                    console.log(id);
                     
                    /*
                if(id){

                    const data_card = await this.fetchServices(id);
                    const cards = [data_card] ;
                    this.setState({cards });
                    console.log(id);
                    console.log(cards);

                }else{

                        const cards = await this.fetchgetServiceseses();
                  this.setState({ cards });
                }
                */
        }

        render() {  

             /*const forms_result =  this.setFormsResults();
              console.log(forms_result);*/
             const { cards } = this.state;
                console.log(cards);
                    console.log(cards.length);
            return (<div className="container px-4 px-lg-5 my-5">
                  
                 
             {cards.length > 0 ? (
                <div className="row gx-4 gx-lg-5   ">
                    {cards.map((card, key) => <Card name={card.name}  id={card.id} key1={key} key={key}  link={card.link} sort={card.sort} text={card.text} linkAlias={card.linkAlias} />)}
                </div>
              ) : (
                "Emry results"
              )}

              <Outlet />

            </div>);
             };

    };


export default Services;  
export const ServicesFunk = props => {
  const {id} = useParams();
  console.log(id);
const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [state] = useState(location.state || {});  

  useEffect(() => {
    navigate(".", { replace: true });  
  }, [navigate]);

  `return <Services id={id} navigate={navigate} {...props} />;`


}  

my app use route
const App = () => (
    
          <Routes>
            


               <Route
                path="/"
                exact 
                element={    <>
                     <TopMenuBlock />
                   <PageContent />
                   <Footer />
                    </>   }
              /> 
              <Route
              path="/form-result"
              exact
               element={    <>
                 <TopMenuBlock /> 
                 <FormResults />
                  <Footer />
                </>   }
            /> 
            <Route
              path="/about/"
              exact
               element={    <>
                 <TopMenuBlock /> 
                 <About />
                  <Footer />
                </>   }
            /> 
            
            <Route
              path="/contact/"
              exact
               element={    <>
                 <TopMenuBlock /> 
                 <Contact />
                  <Footer />
                </>   }
            /> 
            <Route
              path="/services/:id?"
              
               element={    <>
                  <TopMenuBlock /> 
                
                  <ServicesFunk />
                  <Footer />
                </>   }
            > 
           
          </Route>


      </Routes>
   
);

export default App;

when I go to pages
http://localhost:3000/services/1/ и http://localhost:3000/services/2/
the page remains the same, kod
return <Services id={id} navigate={navigate} {...props} />;
does not give a result and is not called. I get the answer here
 const {id} = useParams(); console.log(id);
but not here
`async componentDidUpdate() {
            const {id} = this.state;
                
                console.log(id);`

id - undefined
I tried to find an answer on stackoverflow and other sites, no result

Could you explain the reason for using class components and functional components together? Also, please simplify the example; there is so much unnecessary code, styles, etc.

I provided all the code so that there were no missing details.

Since version v6, there is no class support for the useParams function and others. It can only be called in the function

As per your code, <Services...> seems to be in backticks. Remove that and try
